Help identifying "Room 305" Cartoon?
I remember watching some a (translated) cartoon in Romania about 10-15 years ago called something along the lines of "Room 305"; however, I'm not sure if the title was exactly that, since a Google search yielded nothing. The cartoon was about a group of kids who went to school and their classroom number was always 305. 
One of the characters was a chubby Lithuanian girl with round glasses who played the role of a "nerd". 
One specific episode I remember is when the main character was visiting his grandparents, and a snowstorm hit; the storm cut off all the power, and the character was forced to only access the fridge in a short burst, to make sure that the cold doesn't get out. 

I know this, I know this!
The girl was named Polly and she loved spoons, didn't she.
I think you're just mistaking number - it's called The Kids from room 402 
check it out:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kids_from_Room_402
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242210/ 
It was amazing!

Ah yes that's the one! Thank you!
